# How to improve database performance on Laravel Eloquent handy appends?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So Laravel's `$appends` is a very nice feature. I've got a `products` table, I added `vendor`, `images` and others to the `$appends` array, so my code looks like this:

class Product extends \ResourceModel {

```
protected $appends = ['vendor', 'images'];

function getVendorAttribute() {
    return $this->vendor()->first();
}

function getImages() {
    $this->_images = $this->images()->get();
}
```

Neat huh?

But, not so fas, here's the list of queries that this neat piece of code is executing:

```
select * from `products`;
select * from `images` where `images`.`imageable_id` = 1 and `images`.`imageable_type` = 'Product';
select * from `vendors` where `vendors`.`id` = 1;
select * from `images` where `images`.`imageable_id` = 2 and `images`.`imageable_type` = 'Product';
select * from `vendors` where `vendors`.`id` = 2;
select * from `images` where `images`.`imageable_id` = 3 and `images`.`imageable_type` = 'Product';
select * from `vendors` where `vendors`.`id` = 3;
select * from `images` where `images`.`imageable_id` = 4 and `images`.`imageable_type` = 'Product';
select * from `vendors` where `vendors`.`id` = 4;
select * from `images` where `images`.`imageable_id` = 5 and `images`.`imageable_type` = 'Product';
select * from `vendors` where `vendors`.`id` = 5;
```

Of course, I rather be doing:

```
select * from `products`;
select * from `images` where `images`.`imageable_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and `images`.`imageable_type` = 'Product';
select * from `vendors` where `vendors`.`id` in(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Or even the `JOIN` equivalent.

So, my questions in detail:

1) I'm loading products in pages of 20. This is generating around 41 queries (more actually, I simplified it for the sake of this question). I think this is really harming performance, am I right? 41 simple queries of the first type are indeed more time consuming for an average MySQL box than 3 queries of the second type?

2) Is there a bundled (or packaged, or simple) way of doing this on Laravel before I go mad fixing all my app logic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Laravel's appends isn't smart enough to know to do this out of the box. you can create this functionality yourself by using a `query scope`. In fact, I would never append anything to the model that is built from any type of query. Only formatters and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your methods are using the relationship queries, so they are running a new query every time they are accessed, and are not taking advantage of any lazy or eager loading.

You could resolve this by making sure to eager load your relationships and access the relationship attribute (`$this->vendor` vs `$this->vendor()`) inside the method, but you'll need to rename your `getVendorAttribute()` method so that it doesn't conflict with the relationship attribute.

However, I think what you might be looking for is the `$with` property on the Model. If you set the `$with` property on your Model, the relationships listed by the property will always be eager loaded for that Model. Additionally, since the relationships will always exist, they will always be there when the Model is converted to an array, and there is no need to add anything to your `$appends` property.

So, your class would look something like:

```
class Product extends Model {

    // always eager load the vendor and images relationships
    protected $with = ['vendor', 'images'];

    // relationship to the vendor
    public function vendor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vendor::class);
    }

    // relationship to the images
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
}
```

With the above class, if you were to call `toArray()` or `toJson()` on a loaded `Product` instance, the output will include the related `vendor` and the related `images`.

For additional reading, I would suggest reading up on [relationship methods vs properties](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties) and [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Answer (score -1):

You should eager load the query and modify the accessors to the following:

```
function getVendorFirstAttribute() {
   $vendors = $this->vendor;
   return $vendors->shift();
}

function getImagesAllAttribute() {
    return $this->images;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Your `getVendorAttribute()` method will override the `vendor` relationship attribute, and calling `$this->vendor` inside the method will cause an "Undefined property" error. Additionally, regarding the relationship attribute, `$this->vendor` would already contain the related vendor record, and calling `first()` on that would actually run a new query and return the first vendor record in the database.